# C# How to get the decimal points of a numeric column inside a datatable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, format

Normally the defaultCellStyle.Format is used in a datagridview, but I am wondering whether you can only get (not set) this information from a datatable itself, before setting it equal to a datagridview's datasource.

EDIT: I am populating a datagridview which only contains information based on a datatable. This datagridview therefore doesn't have numeric data, only strings. I would like to add one more column which shows the decimal points, if any, of each numeric column in the datatable on which I am populating this datagridview.

```
DataTable local = new DataTable();
local.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column", typeof(string)));
local.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Unit", typeof(string)));
local.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Decimal Points", typeof(int)));

// Fill columns

myDataGridView.DataSource = local;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can certainly get whatever information is there.  What information are you looking for?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ChrisF I want to display the decimal points of each numeric column of this datatable to the user.

Comment: @David Edited to make it a little more clear hopefully.

Comment: @Iason: A format string on the display should take care of that.  Or perhaps a calculation of the values with `% 1.0` to leave only the decimal component.